# Different code style settings in PhpStorm for php files based on file extension?

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm (and love it!), but the coding standard for my current project uses 4 space indents for .php files and 2 space indents for template files (.phtml).  The template files are traditional php and HTML.  Our code implements a standard Zend Framwork MVC setup.

Is there a way to configure PhpStorm to use one set of code style settings for *.php files and a different set of code style settings for *.phtml files?

**Setting::File Type didn't work**
I've tried associating .phtml files with the HTML file type, but that causes me to lose ALL php language assistance (no PHP syntax highlighting, no code assist, etc.).

**Settings::Template Data Languages didn't work**
I also looked for a solution using the the Template Data Languages setting.  I setup my .phtml files to the File Type HTML, but PHP isn't an available setting, so it appears there is no way to add php language support for HTML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it is not possible.

If you want to have PHP support, file extension has to be associated with PHP file type. That's the only way to have PHP support as PHP is not injectable language in current PhpStorm version/implementation.

You may utilize *TextMate bundles support plugin* and install PHP supported highlighting there. This will allow to assign .phtml extension to another file type. The drawback is that you can only have one language highlighting .. so HTML will not be highlighted + no code completion for actual PHP (that's as far as my simple experiments went with other not-yet-supported languages).